# How do I look into a File and Settings Transfer Wizard back-up?

Tags: windows-xp, backup

Is there a way to look at the imgXXXXX.dat files, which are created by File and Settings Transfer Wizard in Windows XP, without importing them to a user. 
Looking for a way to just pull a few files out of it.

Answer (score 0):

The [USMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722032(WS.10).aspx) documentation is probably your best guess.

But I guess it's faster to import it to a second user and copying the data you need to your main user.